# Swift foreach selected row with class object

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm trying to highlight a selected row in a foreach that's using classes.
The following is working from an example on SO

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: String
    var isActive: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var modelArray = [
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: true),
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(modelArray.indices, id: \.self){ idx in

            Text("\(self.modelArray[idx].a) \(self.modelArray[idx].b) \(self.modelArray[idx].c)")
                .foregroundColor(self.modelArray[idx].isActive ? .red : .green)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.modelArray[idx].isActive = true

                    for i in self.modelArray.indices {
                        if i != idx { self.modelArray[i].isActive = false }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I change the object to a class and initialize it, it will no longer highlight the text on tap. The first object that's initialized to true IS higlighted, and the print command will print the correct bool value, but the text doesn't change.

```
class Model:  ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var id = UUID()
    @Published var a: String
    @Published var b: String
    @Published var c: String
    @Published var isActive: Bool
    
    init(a: String, b: String, c: String, isActive: Bool) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.isActive = isActive
    }
}

@State private var modelArray = [
    Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: true),
    Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
    Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
]

---
ForEach(modelArray.indices, id: \.self){ idx in

Text("\(self.modelArray[idx].a) \(self.modelArray[idx].b) \(self.modelArray[idx].c)")
   .foregroundColor(self.modelArray[idx].isActive ? .red : .green)
   .onTapGesture {
      self.modelArray[idx].isActive.toggle()
      print(self.modelArray[idx].isActive)
   }
}
---
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need the object to be a class, as I'm pulling data in from firebase in a view model.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want class? struct is a proper way

Comment: ... and `ObservableObject` is not appropriate way for `Model`

Comment: I think I assumed the model had to be a class in order to use @Published. I'm coming from android/java world. I'll try changing a few of my other models then. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually also this guide from apple. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app. which suggests you "adopt the **ObservableObject** protocol for model **classes**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach, where you keep your `Model` as struct, and
a `class ViewModel: ObservableObject` that hold your array of `[Model]`. This `ViewModel` will `observe` any changes to your `modelArray` and update the UI.

Such as this example code

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var modelArray: [Model] = [
 Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: true),
 Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
 Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
]
}
```

in `ContentView`

```
   @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

and adjust the code accordingly. For example:

```
   ForEach(viewModel.modelArray.indices, id: \.self){ idx in ...}
```

or simply

```
   ForEach(viewModel.modelArray){ aModel in  ...}
```

EDIT-1: for completeness, here is my test code:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var modelArray: [Model] = [
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: true),
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
        Model(a:"hi", b:"I like", c: "potatoes", isActive: false),
    ]
    // -- here
    func update(model: Model) {
        for i in modelArray.indices {
            if model.id == modelArray[i].id {
                modelArray[i].isActive = true
            } else {
                modelArray[i].isActive = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // <-- here
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: String
    var isActive: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.modelArray){ model in // <-- here
            Text("\(model.a) \(model.b) \(model.c)")
                .foregroundColor(model.isActive ? .red : .green)
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.update(model: model) // <-- here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried both methods, with a slight correction, but neither worked. ForEach(viewModel.modelArray.indices, id: \.self){ idx in ...} ForEach(viewModel.modelArray){ aModel in...} -

Comment: Actually, I might have spoken too soon. I'm trying again with my firebase data..

Comment: updated my answer with some typo corrections.

Comment: This has worked, I had to restructure a few things in how I assign my firebase data, but It all seems to be working fine. Thank you very much. Although I'm still not entirely sure why it doesn't work as with an object that is a class.